# Can't get scripted arrow to work

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to clone something when an arrow is fired.
I'm using this command:

`execute as @e[type=minecraft:arrow] run clone 90 56 33 107 59 30 ~ ~ ~`

But it isn't doing anything at all when I fire an arrow.
It's in a repeating command block, by the way.

Comment: Is there any error message in the lower text box of the command block? What happens if you execute it from chat? Also, you only used `as`, so `~ ~ ~` would still be the coordinates of the command block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your repeating command block either has a redstone signal, or is set to <kbd>always active</kbd>.

The command will also fail if the coordinates `90 56 33 107 59 30` are too far away.

Try to use `at` instead of `as`.

If you use `as`, then your command executes as all arrows, at the location of your command block.
If you use `at`, then your command executes as the command block, at the loaction of every arrow.

The command that you currently have should do something **once**, it should clone whatever is at `90 56 33 107 59 30` to the location of your command block, which effectively replaces the command block with the block at `90 56 30`.

Comment: You can find more information on how to use commands [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/354615/232393)